# Is it possible to split a SQL-cell and afterwards compare the strings?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have this scenario:
A table named `table 1`, with a column named `groups`.
I that column there are a range of groups which I need to split and afterwards compare with the variable `myGroup`

Currently I am doing this:

```
myGroup = 32
trueGroup = false

sql = "select * from table1 where groups like '%" & myGroup & "%'"
set rs = conn.execute(sql)

if not rs.eof
  do until rs.eof
    title = rs("title")
    groups = rs("groups")
    groupsSplitted = split(groups, ",")

    for i = lbound(groupsSplitted) to ubound(groupsSplitted)
      if cint(myGroup) = cint(groupsSplitted(i)) then
        trueGroup = true
      end if
    next

    if trueGroup
      response.write(title)
    end if
  next
end if
```

Is it possible to do all in the SQL line? :)

Comment: A properly designed table structure would have the groups being split off into a separate table, one group per record, making it totally unnecessary to do this kind of splitting. In other words: Fix your table structure, and this problem will go away: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalise your data.

Having multiple values in a single field (comma delimited or otherwise) is a bad anti-pattern.  It destroys performance by blinding the optimiser to use of indexes, and makes queries difficult to write and maintain.

Instead, change your schema to have a 1:many relationship...

```
CREATE TABLE map_title_to_group (
  title_id INT,
  group_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, title_id)
)
```

Then your query is simplified...

```
SELECT title_id FROM map_title_to_group WHERE group_id = ?
```

You can even then also enforce constraints...
- title_id foreign keyed to the table of titles
- group_id foreign keyed to the table of groups

Comment: This was going to be a tongue-in-cheek question, but now I'm actually curious... is there such a thing as a "good anti-pattern" as opposed to "bad anti-pattern"? Apologies for wandering off topic.

Comment: @JonP - Good point, I'd say there are no "good anti-patterns" :)  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern]